# Remove tag [tag:access] and blacklist it

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging, tag-synonyms

The tag [access](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/access) has no description and I've seen it used in at least three different contexts:

- Microsoft Access, but there's already a tag [ms-access](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) for this.
- privileges a user has on an object, but there's already a tag [access-control](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/access-control) which can be used in some cases for this, or just use [privileges](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privileges).
- index access paths, where I think the tag is extraneous. [indexing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indexing) or similar should be enough.

If it was up to me, I would remove this tag and blacklist it.

Comment: Thanks Colin, I've tagged this [meta-tag:feature-request] to bring it to the attention of the SE team. It's a good candidate for blacklisting in my view and better than the alternative which would be to make it a synonym for [tag:ms-access]

Comment: Yes, exactly. Synonym would result in things being incorrectly tagged.